# Some NFC phones can not read tags

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I came across an interesting problem. When I tested NFC on different devices I noticed some NFC devices can not read user memory of RFID tag (ISO 15693). Samsung Galaxy S3, Galaxy Mini 2, Sony Xperia Z2 10" can read all data on tags. But for example with Samsung Galaxy Young (I tried two devices Galaxy Young) can not read user memory although NFC is available. Galaxy Young can read only info about tag like UID, AFI, DSFID, etc.

Some idea how I can recognize devices which can not read user memory of RFID tags? Is there any explanation of why Galaxy Young can not read user memory?

Comment: probably nfc chip embedded in Samsung galaxy Young board is not supporting your nfc card. I also have same problem in designing tablet-pc's in my previous company, and this is because of chip itself. About your question on how to detect; i am not sure how you gonna fix it. if i can find an answer i ll update it here for sure.

Comment: Without specifying which ISO 15693 tag you tried to read out we might not be able to properly help you. Additionally you didn't specify how you read them out. Did you use some app from Google Play or did you develop your own? If the latter how does your reading code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of different NFC tag's with different chip types. To name a few different types: `Ultralight, NTAG213, NTAG215, NTAG216, Mifare 1k` you can see a list [here](http://rapidnfc.com/which_nfc_chip). They all have a different standard and not all standards are supported on each phone.

I had a lot of trouble with the `Mifare` tags in the past on my devices. I used an android app [like this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html) one in the past to check if an tag was compatible with my device. It gives you a lot of information about the scanned tag.

According to [this article](http://www.andytags.com/nfc-tags-compatibility-issues.html#.VTYFNtyqpBc):

> NTAG203 and Topaz 512 Tags are fully compatible with ALL NFC Phones.

You can also refer to the [android developers page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html)

I hope this pushed you in the right direction.